# Seleccionar parte de un texto a partir de una palabra

Tags: python

Tengo una duda como hago para que python encuentre una palabra especifica en un fichero como 'Hola' y lo que tiene a su lado ejemplo 'Hola soy blah blah blah'

```
def File():
    Name = str(input('--> '))
    with open(Name, 'r') as F:
        Content = F.read()

    if 'hola' in Content:
        a = 'hola' #que debo hacer para conseguir lo que tiene a su lado
        print(a)

def Run():
    File()
Run()
```

Comment: Usa el método `readlines` , luego haces un for `a=[line for line in F.readlines() if 'hola in line.strip()]`

Comment: ¿Qué es "lo que tiene a su lado"? ¿lo que sigue a "hola" hasta el fin de línea?

Comment: Por favor leer [ask]. Aunque no lo creas necesario, el título de tu pregunta debe ser más descriptivo y conciso de lo que tienes actualmente. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero de todo, cambia el nombre a la pregunta, ese nombre no ayuda a alguien que esté buscando este mismo problema.

Sobre la pregunta, dices lo que tiene a su lado. Así que seleccionariamos todo lo que hay a partir de Hola

```
def File():
    Name = str(input('--> '))
    with open(Name, 'r') as F:
        Content = F.read()

    if 'hola' in Content:
        a = Content[Content.index('hola')::]
        print(a)

def Run():
    File()
Run()
```

Para el texto

```
Jesucristo minecra minecraft
hola Cristina
He desayunado pan
```

Me Devuelve

```
hola Cristina
He desayunado pan
```

Pero si solo quieres leer esa linea:

```
def File():
    Name = str(input('--> '))
    with open(Name, 'r') as F:
        Content = F.readlines()

        for element in Content:
            if 'hola' in element:
                print(element)

def Run():
    File()
Run()
```

Me Devuelve

```
hola Cristina
```